# distinct rows from bigquery table with array field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table containing a field *candidate* of array type. How can I query distinct rows from this table?

[image]

In this case my query should return just the first row.

Answer (score 4):

I think below is the simplest way and works for any types and length , etc.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(candidate) candidate
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY FORMAT('%T', candidate)
```

Previously I used to use TO_JSON_STRING() for this - but recently realized that FORMAT() fits best for most cases like this

Comment: aaah.. %T behavior: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#t_and_t_behavior

Comment: exactly! :o) depends on case it is either `%T` or `%t` to be used for the best result :o)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select split(combed, ".") as candidate from (
   select distinct array_to_string(candidate, ".") as combed 
   from `dataset.table`
)
```